# How to properly copy files to Application Scripts folder from Sandboxed App?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode11, appstore-sandbox

I'm really confused about how to properly copy files and grant permission to execute e.g. an AppleScript file from a sandboxed application. I've read several articles and threads but the more I read, the more it confuses me.

#### The Task

My app needs to run a very simple `AppleScript` from an `.scpt` file. To do so (if I got this right), I need to copy this file into `Users/thisUser/Library/Application \Scripts/.com.developerName.appName/`. Before I can interact with this folder the user needs to grant access to that folder. This can be done by showing the user an `NSOpenPanel` where he can select the path. After confirmation the app has access to that path and I can copy the file and later run the script (App Sandbox **User Selected File** must be **read/write**). So far so good.

#### The Problem(s)

I find presenting a *Finder* window with an empty folder to select very user unfriendly, so I was wondering if there is anything else I can do. The closest what I have found regarding this problem is **drag & drop** the folder "into the app" - details can be found [here.](https://benscheirman.com/2019/10/troubleshooting-appkit-file-permissions/)

I guess I'm not the only person ever who created a (sandboxed) app which needs to run specific scripts and I can't believe that the above approach is the only possible solution!? Therefore,

> **can I not just have a single window with an OK button and some information above that the app needs permission to write into that folder without showing an entire Finder window?**

When I was looking around for solutions I also came across several settings for the app itself. Unfortunately, the docs are very limited here and I could not really find out what the specific settings actually do and how I could test them (admittedly this is because this is my first ever app for OSX and I have basically no clue what I'm doing). One of which is the **Copy Files** option in the **Build Phase** settings of the app:

[image]

This did sound promising to me since I thought that if I install the app it will automatically copy the file to the Scripts destination (probably with some sort of user prompt) and I can use it. But it does nothing. There is no copy happening at any time, even if I deselect the **Copy only when installing** setting. I have also tried the different destination folders which are available in the dropdown

[image]

and unfortunately also here I

- could not find out what the destinations are
- nor the file has been copied to any of the destination folders on `build`.

I know that people here don't really like to answer questions like this in much detail since it is probably more a *lack of knowledge* on my side but I would really appreciate it if someone could at least help me getting into the right direction and direct me to some resources which tackle my problem!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems like I have found a solution which (at least for me) seems to be more or less user friendly and within Apple's sandbox guidelines.

Again, I'm very new to app development using Xcode and SwiftUI so I'm not sure if this solution is 100% "the right way of doing it". But since it took me ages to find this out, maybe someone else can use it and speed up development!

#### Solution

Like I have mentioned in my question above, I was trying to get rid of the (in my opinion) pretty annoying `NSOpenPanel` Finder prompt, where the user is supposed to select the folder. I further asked about the **Copy Files** setting in the app's **Build Phase** tab - it turned out that this was the solution! Unfortunately, I still don't have any clue about the list of destination which are presented in the dropdown but choosing **Absolute Path** and inserting

```
Users/$USER/Library/Application Scripts/$PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER
```

did the job! The file gets copied on every build into the app's `Application Scripts` directory, from which I can run scripts outside the sandbox.

[image]

The next step was to create a class which executes the script using `NSUserScriptTask`

```
import Foundation

class ExecuteAppleScript {

    var status = ""

    private let scriptfileUrl : URL?


    init() {
        do {
            let destinationURL = try FileManager().url(
                for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.applicationScriptsDirectory,
                in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask,
                appropriateFor:nil,
                create: true)

            self.scriptfileUrl = destinationURL.appendingPathComponent("CreateMailSignature.scpt")
            self.status = "Linking of scriptfile successful!"

        } catch {
            self.status = error.localizedDescription
            self.scriptfileUrl = nil
        }
    }

    func execute() -> String {
        do {
            let _: Void = try NSUserScriptTask(url: self.scriptfileUrl!).execute()
            self.status = "Execution of AppleScript successful!"
        } catch {
            self.status = error.localizedDescription
        }

        return self.status
    }
}
```

Then I have created a *Button View* which handles the request

```
import SwiftUI

struct GenerateSignatureButtonView: View {

    @State var status = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Button(action: {
                self.status = ExecuteAppleScript().execute()
            })
            {
                Text("Generate Signature")
            }
            Text("\(self.status)")
        }
    }
}

struct GenerateSignatureButtonView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GenerateSignatureButtonView()
    }
}
```

When clicking the button a window pops up that the app wants access to control (in my case) the Mail app.

[image]

This user prompt repeats every time the user closes the app, reopens it and clicks the button again. I guess this can be somehow managed with [Security-Scoped-Bookmarks](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16) but I'm not yet sure how. Furthermore, the error handling is not really working in this example since the popup appears *after* the *successful* message appears in the status field. This is probably another big thing to figure out... Asynchronous?

Well, hope this helps!

Comment: Florian, thanks for sharing this! I have been digging for info on this as well, so I am happy to read how you solved things. One (newbee) question: did you verify whether your solution also works when the user installs from the Apple Store? That is: when someone first downloads your application, will the scripts automatically be installed in the "Application Scripts" folder?

Comment: This solution is useless. The file will only be copied on your developer machine...

Comment: @TamásZahola well, why would it only be working on the dev-machine? According to the App Developer Docs, the destination in this post is exactly where application related files go - on every machine with regards to the date of publishing this answer. Moreover, I have distributed a number of apps, including this solution, to friends and family - it was (and still is) working on all of the different machines.

Comment: You're adding a Copy Files build phase to your Xcode project, which will be executed by Xcode when building the target. When you create a .app bundle from this app there's simply no mechanism which could place this file to the necessary location on the users' computer.