# Is there an NSOpenPanel alternative or can the panel be styled differently in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, appstore-sandbox, nsopenpanel

I have asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62213688/how-to-properly-copy-files-to-application-scripts-folder-from-sandboxed-app) and at even at the [Apple Developer's Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/133954). It seems like either I have the questions wrong or no one can / want's to comment on this subject.

#### The problem

I want to grant access to a folder outside the sandbox of my application. I know I can do this with an `NSOpenPanel` dialog - a modal popping up, where the folder is pre-selected, thus an empty view and the user is supposed to press an *OK* button.

#### The question

Since I find this *"empty folder view with a random OK button"* not really user friendly, I was wondering if there is a possibility to either

- use an `NSOpenPanel` alternative or
- adjust the styling of the panel

so that I simply have a modal popping up which alerts the user that the app needs access to a folder (which will be printed out in the alert window), with an *OK* and a *Cancel* button. I don't want to show locations on the system, an empty box of a folder and all the other stuff which is presented.

To clarify, this is what I have:

[image]

and this is what I want (or something similar):

[image]

I would really appreciate if someone could tell me if this is possible or not. At least point me to some reference (I could not find anything so far).

Thanks!

Comment: i was looking for something similar without any success.

Comment: That is really weird! I mean, I have seen solutions where you can *drag* the folder into your application, so why is it not possible to have a simple prompt? I can’t believe no one else ever had the same problem?

Comment: dragging a folder onto your app will add it to the sandbox. EVERYONE implementing the sandbox has this problem.

Comment: Dragging a folder is an instance of a user chosen file. You get a security scoped URL on the pasteboard.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me from getting crazy... Well I guess I just have to deal with it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Not possible.

NSOpenPanel & NSSavePanel have a special relationship for sandboxed apps. They are sort of an app called PowerBox within your app that allow the user to pick a file or folder and return a security scoped URL to your code.

They are described in the [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW17)

As such if you can’t do it using the NSSavePanel/NSOpenPanel API then it can’t be done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I did use the *Copy Files* setting and installed the script in the Application Scripts folder but I need to update the script file with user inputs from within the app.

Comment: Yes, so if you put those scripts in the *container* folder you would get access to them without needing to interact with the user.

Comment: Sorry for this stupid question but where do I find the *Container* folder? And I thought that I can only run custom scripts from within `.../Library/Application Scripts/com.developer.appName/`?

Comment: My bad. `NSApplicationScriptsDirectory` takes you to the scripts directory you already use while  `NSLibraryDirectory` will get you to `/Users/sallyjones/Library/Containers/com.developer.theApp/Data/Library/` and that area below `/Users/sallyjones/Library/Containers/com.developer.theApp/Data` is your applications free zone.

Comment: Consider that running scripts with `NSUserAppleScriptTask` (the only way to run custom scripts in the sandbox) requires the location of the scripts in `Application Scripts`

Comment: @vadian yep correct,  and although `Application Scripts` mirrors into the container `Library` you still can't write there via sandbox without explicit user permission.  The container  isn't quite as free and wild as I might think.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I understand that I will not get around asking the user to give folder / file access via NSOpenPanel. I think the solution by dragging the folder into the app seems to be the most *user friendly* way.

Comment: Yes , that might be the best way. Particularly if you can show a gif/animation of the action you want. Remember to save the security scoped bookmark when you do this  otherwise the perms to the URL will only last for the app session. Good luck. :-)